# Typo3 Text element not saves my large content. What is the limit of text element?

Tags: typo3

I created regular Text content element in typo3. My content is huge. Typo3 is not saving whole data, it saves only part of my data.

What is the limitation of Text element ?

Typo3 Version 4.4.8

Answer (score 1):

In a standard installation, the `bodytext` column of the `tt_content` table is defined as MEDIUMTEXT (equvalent to MEDIUMBLOB) in MySQL. According to [this site](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_data_types.php) it can have a maximum length of *16,777,215 characters*.

I have not found any other limitation to the text content element in TYPO3, and I just tested this with more than 350,000 characters in a 4.5.2 installation - don't want to be caught writing bogus here :).

However, the MySQL server limits the package size of each query. [Read more here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=150255)

> The real maximum size depends on the maximum size allowed by your
>   filesystem (mostly is 2 GB), since is highly unlikely that you can load
>   a 4GB file to the database if your OS allows you only 2GB. [...]. The
>   database engine has a `max_allowed_packet` limit, which prevents the
>   client from dealing with packets exceeding such barrier

Changing the `max_allowed_packet` value in *my.cnf* from it's default 1MB to 32MB or higher might help.

In your case, you should also check for non-standard characters in your text that break the content output of the database field. [See here](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2008-August/052686.html).